# Draw 3D model on existing activity

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, 3d-model

I want to draw a 3d model on an existing activity which already has some buttons, texts and images. I know we can do it using OpenGLES but in that it will create a window to draw the 3D graphics. I want it to be like a transparent model. Can anybody please help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way, but you can try this.

Combining UI-elements and OGL view together:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state) { 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gl);
        surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.oglView);
        surfaceView.init(this.getApplicationContext());
    } 
}

public class SurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private SceneRenderer renderer;
    public SurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
    }

    public void init(Context context) {
        renderer = new SceneRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
        ...
    }
}
```

And create layout activity_gl.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        tools:context=".activities.GameActivity">
    <com.app.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/oglView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <TextView ... />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But to create a transparency effect, it's probably better to add transparency to the elements of "frame" layout like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkYellow"
        android:alpha="0.5">
        <TextView ... />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.app.SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/oglView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

From my own experience transparency affects performance, so if there is animation, it is better not to use transparency.

To update UI-elements from the render thread, can use Handler/Looper.